# Map values of 3 lists in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 3 lists.

The name list: `brad, scott, bryan`

Their corresponding age: `20, 25, 23`

The colors they like respectively: `red, orange, green`.

When I loop through the name list, I want to get age `20` and color `red` for name `brad`.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself or are you just asking people to do your homework for you?

Comment: if those are distinct lists, why not to use a list indexing? like names[0], ages[0], colors[0]? Or did I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mat [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) arbitrary number of sequences.

```
names = ['brad', 'scott', 'bryan']
colors = ['red', 'orange', 'green']
ages = [20, 25, 23]
for name, color, age in zip(names, colors, ages):
    print name, color, age
```

Comment: You are the boss, SIR. Is there a way I can refer any question that I have directly to you. I just started learning ABC of python.
Else please help me with your email so I can refer directly to you.
Anyways, thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ['brad', 'scott', 'bryan']
colors = ['red', 'orange', 'green']
ages = [20, 25, 23]

for i, val in enumerate(names):
    print "{} {} {}".format(val, colors[i], ages[i])
```